# How can I make this function work with php 7.2?

Tags: php, mysql, database, select, migration

I have this piece of code that works fine with php5.6 but it breaks with php7.2.
I had three errors and I was able to fix two, I believe :)

```
$link = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password);
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect !');
    exit();
}
else{
    mysql_set_charset('utf8',$link);
    mysql_select_db($database, $link) or die('Could not select database.');
    }
```

this is what I have so far

```
$link = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password);
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect !');
    exit();
}
else{
    mysqli_set_charset('utf8',$link);
    mysqli_select_db($database, $link) or die('Could not select database.');
    }
```

**Fatal error** with mysql_select_db()

How can I make this function work with php 7.2? any help will be greatly appreciated, thank you in advance!!

Comment: The `mysql_*` functions have been deprecated since v5.5 (Jun 2013) and removed since v7.0 (Dec 2015). Instead use [**mysqli**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) functions with [**prepared statements**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) and [**bound parameters**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php).

Comment: I *highly* suggest you read through the manual and the syntax used for the mysqli api: http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php - You will see that what you tried, differs from it.

Comment: Your question title is not very informative.  Remember that future researchers are going to want to _find_ the knowledge that you will eventually received.  Please make your title as clear, informative, and searchable as logically possible.  Right now, your title is terribly vague.

Comment: Why not declare the database in your `$link` declaration?  You _did_ read the manual before coming here, right?

Comment: You have reversed `$database` and `$link`.  I am voting to close as _Off-topic: Typo_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [mysqli_* API](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) requires that the database connection come first (unlike the old and deprecated [mysql_* API](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysql.php) which is no longer supported in PHP 7.2):

```
$link = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password);
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect !');
    exit();
}
else{
    mysqli_set_charset($link, 'utf8');
    mysqli_select_db($link, $database) or die('Could not select database.');
    }
```

References:

- http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysqli-connect.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php
- http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.set-charset.php

Make sure that you did in fact assign something to the `$database` variable; that wasn't included in your post.

Edit: As stated in comments by Riggs, you can use 4 arguments for the connection instead.

I.e.:

```
$link = mysqli_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $database);
```

The choice is yours.

Comment:

> Much better to put the database as param 4 of the connect. mysqli_select_db() is really only for when you want to switch from one db to another using the same connection – RiggsFolly

...indeed.

---

In regards to the error:

> Fatal error with mysql_select_db()

I hope that you're not mixing this with anything else. Those different MySQL API's do not intermix with each other.

That error alone means that it is "fatal" error as shown and is the result of that API not being supported by your server.

Using PHP's error reporting and set to catch and display, would have (most likely) thrown you an error of deprecation and/or possibly not being supported.

Reference:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: There was a downvote that was removed. Believe me, I don't care. Do what you want.

Comment: Much better to put the database as param 4 of the connect. `mysqli_select_db()` is really only for when you want to switch from one db to another using the same connection

Comment: @RiggsFolly either way ;-)

Comment: My aim is not good, I hit the wrong arrow :)

Comment: @RiggsFolly heh! I made an edit in regards to what you mentioned about the connection paramaters; they've 2 options.

Comment: Hey Funk Forty Niner, You are right, reversing the parameters fix the problem, woohoo!!. I am sorry i was vague in my question, I'll work on that. Thank you everyone :)

Comment: @mp5163093 Glad to hear that this was resolved. You could consider accepting the answer. This is done on a voluntary basis, but it does inform everyone and the system that a solution was found and will mark it such. *Cheers*